# Short Story "Slow Topiary"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, soft-sci-fi

Short Story: Woman suffering from terminal cancer meets weird guy who has a topiary in his isolated home that is the size of a large oa

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! What about this story was sci-fi or fantasy? Is there anything else you remember?

Comment: It looks like your question cuts off; can you [edit] it to complete it?

Comment: If Organic Marble has the right answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

"[Slow Sculpture](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40937)" by Theodore Sturgeon.

An embittered scientific genius cures a woman that shows up at his doorstep of breast cancer.

The fictional cancer treatment makes it sf.

It ends

> ..."I had a crazy kind of image. Do you think two sick twisted trees
> ever made bonsai out of one another?"
>
> "What's your name?" he asked her.